Find the limit using Riemann Sum
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sqrt[n]{\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n-1)!}}
$$
I'm currently learning Riemann Integral in my Calculus 1 class at Uni and tackled this problem. This is a completely new problem to me (I've done some easier assignments but this exercise came as a completely different form) and I can't really think of any possible solution to solve this yet! Please provide me with the guidance! Thank a lot!!!!!

Using logarithms would be helpful.

Take logarithms and use Stirling approximation

Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4021523/42969

Big Hint
Set $u_n=\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n-1)!}}$. Then, $$\log(u_n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\log\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }\int_0^1\log(1+x)\,\mathrm d x.$$
I let you conclude.

Thank you, sir. It's a great help! Lots of appreciation

We have Stirling Theory：
$n! \sim (2\pi n)^{\frac{1}{2}}(\frac{n}{e})^{n}$
so,we have
$$(2n-1)!\sim (2\pi(2n-1))^{\frac{1}{2}}(\frac{2n-1}{e})^{2n-1}$$
$$(n-1)!\sim (2\pi(n-1))^{\frac{1}{2}}(\frac{n-1}{e})^{n-1}$$
hence,the original limitation equals to
$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{1}{n}(\frac{2n-1}{n-1})^{\frac{1}{2n}}\frac{1}{e}(\frac{2n-1}{n-1})^{\frac{n-1}{n}}(2n-1)}$
$$\text{however,}\lim_{n \to \infty}{(\frac{2n-1}{n-1})^{\frac{1}{2n}}}=1$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{(\frac{2n-1}{n-1})^{n-1}{n}}=2$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{2n-1}{n}}=2$$
hence,the original limitation equals to
$\frac{4}{e}$

I haven't heard about Stirling approximation before. Would definitely look it up online. Thanks a lot!
